# Loop all files and insert file headers

Tags: bash

Assume I have this dummy project:

```
$tree -L 3 ~/my-proj
./dir/foo.sh
./bar.sh
```

I want to insert copyright file header into all *.sh files, for example my header is:

```
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2015 by MyCompany, Inc.
 *  All rights reserved.
 */
```

I am struggling it is multiline, I managed to write script below but not work for multiline:

```
#!/bin/sh
HEADER=$(cat<<EOH
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2015 by MyCompany, Inc.
 *  All rights reserved.
 */
)

find ~/my-proj/*.sh -exec sed -i "1s/^/$HEADER\n/" {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
header='/*\n *  Copyright (c) 2015 by MyCompany, Inc.\n *  All rights reserved.\n */\n'
find ~/my-proj/*.sh -exec sed -i "1s|^|$header|" {} \;
```

Notes:

1. The shell will substitute the value of `$header` directly into the sed command.  This allows injection of arbitrary commands into the sed script.  Do **not** do this unless you trust the source of the `header`.
2. The header contains `/` characters.  Either those characters have to be escaped or else the substitute command must use a different delimiter.  In the above, `|` was used as the delimiter.
3. It is best practice to use lower or mixed-case for shell variables.  The system uses upper case for its variables and, while it is not a problem in this case, you don't want to accidentally overwrite one.

#### Example

To illustrate the revised sed command, consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
```

The sed command produces:

```
$ sed "1s|^|$header|" file
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2015 by MyCompany, Inc.
 *  All rights reserved.
 */
1
2
3
```